# how to take subnet mask for an IP

Tags: networking, ip, subnet, netmask

I found this problem in a textbook, and I do not understand the solution:

Find the subnet which the IP: `192.168.1.25` belongs to.
Here is what they did:

1. `255.255.255.224` for `192.168.1.25` and do a binary `AND` operation.
2. Then take the subnet mask because of postfix `/27` CIDR postfix in the IP.

But why? In the problem definition, the number `/27` was not given. How did they come up with that?

Comment: Must be a misprint then. The CIDR postfix indicates the mask bits, e.g. `192.168.1.25/27` means 27 mask bits; this corresponds to the subnet mask `255.255.255.224`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They know that the the /27 CIDR is 27 as they used the subnet mask of 255.255.255.224.  The CIDR is the number of available IP's since 255.255.255.255-255.255.255.224 is 31.
This is a number range 0-31 or a range of 32 possible values. This corresponds to 2^5. So therefore 2^32 - 2^5 = 2^27 with 27 being your CIDR.

Comment: To look at it another way an IPV4 address is made up of 4 bytes = 8 x 4 bits = 32 bits.  A /27 means the left most 27 bits are 1 (or if you prefer 32-27=5 0 bits on the right), so in binary it would look like 11111111.11111111.1110000  which converts in decimal to 255.255.255.224